# Delphi : How to plot a simple 2d graph?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi for my computer science coursework and need my program to plot a simple graph for projectile motion. I've struggled in finding a way to implement this and was wondering if anyone has had experience in drawing graphs or would be able to point me in the right direction.

The main idea that I have tried is plotting all the x values and drawing a line to the corresponding y value at that given time, but each time it comes out really weird and doesn't work.

Comment: Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is too broad to ask here. Sorry. The question should be closed and removed. To give you a hint though, you should consider using the TeeChart library that ships with Delphi. That makes the task trivially easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps for simple graph:
1. Provide data values in array/list
2. Find minimal and maximal values for X and Y components
3. Calculate linear formulas for mapping data values to screen coordinates (min x = > left of rectangle for drawing and so on)
4. Draw line segments applying formulas to get coordinates
5. If needed, draw axes

P.S. Is TChart using prohibited?

Comment: what include does TChart need for usage?

Comment: @Rolandas Ulevicius This answer describes plotting simple graph **without** TChart usage. When you put TChart on the form, IDE adds needed units into `uses` clause.

Comment: i just want to note for someone like me in the future who installed 10.4 IDE version. when you install it there is a checkmark for teechart component, because it is optional.

Comment: @Rolandas Ulevicius This fact has no relation to the question, so it's worth to remove the last comments

Answer (score 0):

I agree that TChart that ships with Delphi is enough to do that task. Anyway you can check this [page](http://www.davdata.nl/math/functionplotting.html) also.